# Trying to print out the elements of a linked list (with multiple classes)

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

So I have an issue that has been bugging me for days now. I have 3 classes : Film, Csalad, Dokumentum. These 3 classes describe movie/film categories, basically "Csalad" is family friendly films, "Dokumentum" is a document film. And everything else is in the Film class.
The Film class is the parent class, which has a few a private char* typed small "arrays" (like: char* cim[25+1], that's for the title). And it's child classes has some special private variables like: char* eletkor[2+1] for the Csalad class.
The problem is that I have succesfully read my necassery data from a txt file, into a syngly linked list(in the txt file every line has a special type with that I can easly decide which film is in which category, and make them into the right class, for example: if something is a simple film I make for them in the Film constructor, if it's a family friendly film I make them in the Csalad constructor). But I have problems printing them onto the screen.
My main goal is to go through my linked list and basically print every single data onto the screen. It sounds easy, but it's not, cause I can't find a method that can both print out the title for example (which is located in the Film class, and intherited by every single other class like Csalad) and can print out Csalad's private variable eletkor.

Can you guys help me?

Here's some code:

"kov" means next in English.

**Film.h**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
class Film{
private:
    char cim[25+1], kiadas[4+1], idotartam[4+1], tema[25+1];
    int hossz;

public:
    Film* kov;

    //Konstruktor   
    Film(char* dcim, char* dkiadas, char* didotartam, char* dtema, int dhossz){
        strcpy(cim, dcim);
        strcpy(kiadas, dkiadas);
        strcpy(idotartam, didotartam);
        strcpy(tema, dtema);
        kov = NULL;
        hossz = dhossz;
    }

    //Masolo konstruktor
    Film(const Film& masolando){
        strcpy(this->cim, masolando.cim);
        strcpy(this->kiadas, masolando.kiadas);
        strcpy(this->idotartam, masolando.idotartam);
        strcpy(this->tema, masolando.tema);
        this->kov = masolando.kov;
    }

    //Getterek
    char* getCim(){
        return cim;
    }

    int getHossz(){
        return hossz;
    }
};
```

**Csalad.h**

```
#include "Film.h"

class Csalad : public Film{
private:
    char eletkor[2+1];

public:
    Csalad(char* dcim, char* dkiadas, char* didotartam, char* dtema, char* deletkor, int dhossz):Film(dcim, dkiadas, didotartam, dtema, dhossz){
        strcpy(eletkor, deletkor);
    }

    char* getEletkor(){
        return eletkor;
    }

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os){
        os << "Cs.Cim: " << getCim() << " " << "Eletkor: " << getEletkor();
        return os;
    }
};
```

Dokumentum.h looks similar to Csalad.h it doesn't really matter at this point.

Those ostreams were my pathetic tries in the main funciton. I make the linked list via a function called "beolvas" and it gives out a Film* type pointer. So my main looks something like this:

```
int main(){
    Film* eleje = NULL;
    eleje = beolvas(eleje);
    if(eleje == NULL){
        cout << "Hiba a beolvasással" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For the printing part, I have been trying to make something like this:

```
for(*SOME KIND OF A TYPE OR SOMETHING* mozgo = eleje; mozgo != NULL; mozgo = mozgo->kov){
    printing...
}
```

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string` instead of `char[]`? It makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: I'll try that, but one of the criteria is that I can't(musn't) use STL containers, and I think that string is one of them. (Thanks for the ";" heads up, i corrected it)

Comment: Yes it is indeed. Ok, that's unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A virtual print() function solved the problem, I didn't tought that it would be that easy. I over thought it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its a strong requirement to use `char` arrays but I will be explaining one possible implementation you can have with standard C++. Know that all `std::string` operations have an equivalent C style operation you can perform (albeit, with a lot more boiler plate code)

Consider the following constraints:

- A film has basic properties representable as a string
- Derived classes have custom properties that are representable as a string
- Printing a film or derived class MUST present all properties as a string

First let's consider the string representation for `Film` and its derived classes

```cpp
#include <string> //std::string
#include <sstream> //std::stringstream

class Film
{
public:
  std::string toString()const
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Title: " << title;
    ss << toStringDerived();
    return ss.str();
  }

  virtual std::string toStringDerived()const { return ""; }

private:
  std::string title;
};
```

Realize that I have seperated the string representation functions into 2 seperate functions, `toString` and `toStringDerived`. All classes which inherit from `Film` now have the option to override their string representation function.

Splitting the base definition from the derived definition for the `toString` also adds one benefit, all derived classes will always print the base class properties as long as the callsite uses the `toString` function provided in the base class.

Now let's see a possible derived class implementation

```cpp
class FamFriendly : public Film
{
public:
  virtual std::string toStringDerived()const override
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "Family: " << family << "\n";
    return ss.str();
  }

private:
  std::string family;
};
```

We see that the derived class have the option to customize their portion of their own string representation without knowing the base classes string representation.

Usage will now be as such

```cpp
Film* currFilm = getFilmLinkedList(...);
while(currFilm != nullptr)
{
  std::cout << currFilm->toString() << "\n"
  currFilm = currFilm->next();
}
```